# RSelenium Error in envRefInferField

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am struggling all day with RSelenium. I have read everything I could find on net about the issue. And after all I am getting some earnings and errors I didn't get in the first place. When I execute `checkForServer()`, I get the watning:

```
Warning message:
checkForServer is deprecated.
Users in future can find the function in file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "example/serverUtils").
The sourcing/starting of a Selenium Server is a users responsiblity. 
Options include manually starting a server see vignette("RSelenium-basics", package = "RSelenium")
and running a docker container see  vignette("RSelenium-docker", package = "RSelenium")
```

When I execute `startServer()`, I get the same warning as above.

In the end, when I run the code `remDr <-remoteDriver()` and `remDr$open()`, I get error:

```
Selenium message: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I have also tried with chrome, but without succes.

Comment: As of firefox 48 geckodriver is needed see https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/81 . Consider running a Docker container see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker

Comment: I have run code from github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/81. Warning massage is still there but there is no error any more. But there is another issue now. When I type `remDr$navigate("http://www.bbc.co.uk")` or any other site inside brackets it just doesn't execute the code? In Rstudio, that red stop button is on, it seems it will execute but it never does.

Comment: Ok. I had to uninstall skype click to call from control panel because it oped out every time I ran the Selenium